# Deleting multiple (50+) items from recycler view is throwing exception (Stacktrace attached)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

The following is the recycler view defined with the animation:

```
mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(fragmentActivity, 2));
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mAdapter = new MediaGridAdapter(fragmentActivity, mediaModels);

MyScaleInAnimator animator = new MyScaleInAnimator(mAdapter);
animator.setAddDuration(100);
animator.setRemoveDuration(100);
mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(animator);
```

The following is how I remove items from the recycler view:

```
public void removeData(String fileType, int position, Context context) {
   mediaModels.remove(position);
   notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

(When I am deleting multiple items, this method is called multiple times iterativey).
**Problem:**
When I select a small numbers of items from the recycler view, the above delete method functions as expected. But If I select a large number of items(50-100) & delete immediately, the following exception is thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.akl.alldrive, PID: 26558
                 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{f308d5b position=54 id=-1, oldPos=74, pLpos:54 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{7b12cb3 VFED.V... ......I. 0,147-1080,1857 #7f0a0099 app:id/list1}, adapter:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.adapters.ScaleInAnimationAdapter@780c270, layout:android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager@fb119e9, context:com.akl.alldrive.activities.BaseActivity@2c3cc96
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.validateViewHolderForOffsetPosition(RecyclerView.java:5715)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5898)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:557)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3875)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3639)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1888)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:407)
                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:778)
                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:710)
                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6798)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
                 Process: com.akl.alldrive, PID: 26558
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{7b12cb3 VFED.V... ......I. 0,147-1080,1857 #7f0a0099 app:id/list1}, adapter:jp.wasabeef.recyclerview.adapters.ScaleInAnimationAdapter@780c270, layout:android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager@fb119e9, context:com.akl.alldrive.activities.BaseActivity@2c3cc96
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2880)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onItemRangeRemoved(RecyclerView.java:5308)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeRemoved(RecyclerView.java:12032)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemRemoved(RecyclerView.java:7231)
                     at com.akl.alldrive.adapters.MediaGridAdapter.removeData(MediaGridAdapter.java:60)
```

How to get around this issue?

Comment: If you want to remove multiple items from a RecyclerView at once, you should be using `notifyItemRangeRemoved()`, rather than doing it one at a time.

Comment: post a snippet of what data you are dealing with for better clarification.

Comment: @TheWanderer, correct me if I am wrong... `notifyItemRangeRemoved()` is used if I select a continuous range of items like 1 to 5 or 4 to 9. But in my case, the selection can be not continuous. I mean,  it is possible to select 3 items at positions 5, 9 & 14 ( 3 random non-continuous items) What will be the range in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IndexOutOfBoundsException

is thrown if you run out of "The Bounds" of whatever you iterating, To fix in recyclerview you need to implement a mechanism to shift the items position up whenever you delete, so it will still be in "The bounds".

Use `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());`

From documentation: "You should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a click listener), use `RecyclerView.ViewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` which will have the updated adapter position."

Comment: I agree to your point. But isn't the intention of using `notifyItemRemoved(position);` to shift these items?

Comment: check the editted answer, btw you are absolutley correct thats what notifyItemRemoved does.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing one item at a time and then notifying for each item removed, try doing it all at once.

An example using some MediaModel class:

```
ArrayList<MediaModel> itemsToRemove = /* however you obtain your list of items to remove */;

medialModel.removeAll(itemsToRemove);

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` error is happened because you're are trying to remove a non-existing item from your adapter. You can't depends on item index position when trying to remove non-continuous items. For example, when you're trying to sequentially remove item on 1, 3, 8, and 9 index position in a list with size of 10, you will be given error `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and stopped after position 1 and 3 are removed. And you didn't actually remove the correct item because when you have remove the item at position 1, the previous item at position 3 is now moved to position 2.

You can solve the problem by using an **id** as your item identifier. Change your data model if it didn't have an id:

```
public class MediaModel {
  private int id;

  // your other data

  // setter and getter

}
```

Then, when removing an item, check against the id not against the position. Something like this:

```
public void removeData(String fileType, int id) {
    int position = -1; // no item found
    for (int i = 0; i < mediaModels.size(); i++) {
      MediaModel model = mediaModels.get(i);
      if(model.getId() == id) {
         position = i;
         break; // we have found the item, so stop searching.
      }

      if(position >= 0) {
         mediaModels.remove(position);
         notifyItemRemoved(position);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code is that you try to access the data from the mediaModels through positions.This in some cases will result to an index out of bound exception because when you call `mediaModels.remove(position)`, it removes the element from that position and adjusts/shifts other elements e.g if I have 5 elements in mediaModels:hamburger, sandwich, pizza, icecream, hotdog...and I call mediaModels.remove(position) where position is 1,this removes sandwich and shifts pizza,icecream,hotdog to fill the empty position so now the size of the mediaModels is now 4 and no longer 5. If I then call `mediaModels.remove(position)` where position is 4, this results to an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because the size of mediaModels list has been changed.

So what you need to do is compare the element you want to delete with the elements in mediaModels in a loop to find the exact position you need then put that position value in:

```java
mediaModels.remove(i);
notifyItemRemoved(i);
```

I replace method parameter position with targetElement and assume it's a String just for illustration,so your code should look like this:

```java
public void removeData(String fileType, String targetElement, Context context) 
{
    for(int i=0;i<mediaModels.size();++i) {
        if(mediaModels.get(i).equals(targetElement){//we have found the position                                           
           mediaModels.remove(i);
           notifyItemRemoved(i);
           break;
        }
    }
}
```